# Autorelease methods leaking

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

Hi everyone,

I'm stuck these days on some memory leaks. The app I'm making is working like that :

1 - Loads a file into memory
2 - Create a screen according to some values read on that file
3 - Display the view

Far from now everything is normal when I start the app and get the first screen. There is no leaks.

But when I want to load an other screen from the current view I got plenty of leaks from autoreleased objects. And I don't understand because when I load a new view from the current one the process is similar :

1 - Desctruction of the current view
2 - Loads a file into memory
3 - Create a screen according to some values read on that file
4 - Display the view

Here are some concrete example of what is leaking :

```
-(NSString*)pathForApplicationName:(NSString*)appName
                         withImage:(NSString*)imagePath { 
       NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths lastObject];
       return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/assets/www/%@",documentPath,[self convertSpacesInDashes:appName],imagePath];
 }
```

The stringWithFormat:.. is leaking. An other example :

```
-(UIColor*)convertHexColorToUIColor:(NSString*)hexColor {

    if ([hexColor length] == 7) {
        unsigned c = 0;
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexColor];
        [scanner setScanLocation:1];
        [scanner scanHexInt:&c];


        return [UIColor colorWithRed:((c>>16)&0xFF)/255.0 
                               green:((c>>8)&0xFF)/255.0 
                                blue:(©&0xFF)/255.0 
                               alpha:1.];
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Same, colorWithRed:.. is leaking.

I've read apple's documentation regarding autoreleased objects. And I've even tried to recreate a new pool like that, without any success :

```
-(UIView)myFonctionWhoGenerateScreens:

    for () {

        NSAutoreleasePool *subPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        // There are all of the autoreleased method calls that are leaking...

        [subPool drain];

    }    
}
```

I think I am missing something. Does anyone has an idea?

Leak backtrace [image]

Thanks a lot.

Edit :

Here is how the return of the leaking function is handled in applyPropertyName:withPropertyType:onComponent:withValue:forStyling method :

```
else if ([propertyType isEqualToString:@"AB_IMAGE"]) {

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self pathForApplicationName:applicationName
                                                                             withImage:value]];
        @try {
            [component setValue:image
                         forKey:propertyName];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
#if DEBUG_CONTROLLER
            NSLog(@" %@ Not key-value compliant for <%@,%@>",component,propertyName,image);
#endif
        }
    }
```

Edit 2 :
Here is the complete back trace http://ganzolo.free.fr/leak/%20Leak.zip

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with those two methods.  Whether or not there's a leak would depend on what their caller does with the returned object.  What is reporting a leak?

Comment: I've added a screenshot. I keep looking the code and thinking the same that everything is fine... :(

Comment: I still suspect that the problem is in the caller rather than the method.  How is the return value handled in the `addPropertyName...` method?  (Or in whichever method up that chain actually uses the path.)

Comment: I've edited my post, I've checked convertSpacesInDashes. It's pretty straight forward, just one line : return [spacedAppName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"-"];

Comment: I'm not seeing it.  Should I assume "Product->Analyze" doesn't give any warnings?  Also, is there a way to get the leaks detection function to show the retain count history of your string?  (I use that to diagnose zombies but I'm not as familiar with this part of the tool.)

Comment: Unfortunately he doesn't give anything. I do not know about this functionality. Is there anything else to do about the autoreleased pool?

Comment: I've put the complete backtrace as attachment to my question if it can helps.. thanks for helping me

Comment: I was just experimenting with Instruments.  If you look at the table of leaks (not the backtrace) and click the small arrow beside the leaked object's address, it shows a screen with the retain count history and what code location is responsible.  This could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your Leak document, and picking the `[NSString stringWithFormat]` object at address 0xdec95c0 as an example, it shows balanced retain count operations for the Foundation, ImageIO, and CoreGraphics use of the object but `ABTwoImageItemImageLeftComponent` is still holding an unreleased reference.

```
0   0xdec95c0   CFString (immutable)    Malloc  1   00:39.994.343   144 Foundation  +[NSString stringWithFormat:]
1   0xdec95c0   CFString (immutable)    Autorelease <null>  00:39.994.376   0   Foundation  +[NSString stringWithFormat:]
2   0xdec95c0   CFString (immutable)    CFRetain    2   00:39.994.397   0   iOS Preview App -[ABTwoImageItemImageLeftComponent setSrcProperty:]
3   0xdec95c0   CFString (immutable)    CFRetain    3   00:39.996.231   0   ImageIO CGImageReadCreateWithFile
4   0xdec95c0   CFString (immutable)    CFRetain    4   00:39.998.012   0   CoreGraphics    CGPropertiesSetProperty
5   0xdec95c0   CFString (immutable)    CFRelease   3   00:40.362.865   0   Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool release]
6   0xdec95c0   CFString (immutable)    CFRelease   2   01:14.892.330   0   CoreGraphics    CGPropertiesRelease
7   0xdec95c0   CFString (immutable)    CFRelease   1   01:14.892.921   0   ImageIO releaseInfoJPEG
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I forgot to release some properties. This doesn't resolved my issue. But I'll go through all my code to see if there is no other case like that...

Comment: It looks quite consistent.  There are four images in the leak list and, looking at them, they're held by either ABFooterComponent or ABTitleBarComponent objects.  The NSNumber at the top of the list is held by a ABFacebookAlbumComponent, etc.  (If you clean these up, what's the remaining problem?)

Comment: I've cleaned all components by setting for all properties nil in dealloc method (there was few missing). The result is the same about 1.55Ko leak with the same test scenario.

Comment: But I've seen that the dealloc of each "component" is never called which is stranged because the view (which held all of the component) has its dealloc method called. And since each component are supposed to have only one retain count (addSubview: method after an autorelease call) they should release :(. I'll check again

Comment: I forgot to precise one other thing, the code who is leaking is on a library. My project is separate in two parts. The core part which contains 90% of the code and a wrapper (just presentation app). I'm compiling it as a static library. I don't know if it can make weird autorelease behaviors. :(

Comment: I haven't seen any evidence of autorelease doing anything strange here.  If you can get these "AB???Component" objects dealloc'd and release their properties, I think most of your problems will go away.

Comment: Ok it is working now. I'll explain what was it... It's "funny"... Few hours ago I was changing the name of a folder (a top top top parent folder of my current project...). Since that time everytime I was compiling I never get the new version of the library in my preview project... Because on my library I have a script which take the svn revision number and put it in info.plist at every build... This script was broken and prevent (I don't know how) my Library to compile correctly. So I was basically doing some modification that I was never testing...

Comment: I would like to give a big thanks to you because your last answer was the right one :) Thanks a lot

Comment: PS : I never get any error messages from the compilation process... Everything was looking fine. But didn't, strange...